# Nginx Ingress Controller not curling localhost on worker nodes

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

CentOS 7, 3 VMs -- 1 master and 2 workers, Kubernetes 1.26 (kubelet is 1.25.5.0), cri-dockerd, Calico CNI

```
# kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME        STATUS   ROLES           AGE     VERSION   INTERNAL-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                KERNEL-VERSION                CONTAINER-RUNTIME
rxxxx-vm1   Ready    control-plane   4h48m   v1.25.5   10.253.137.20   <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   3.10.0-1160.80.1.el7.x86_64   docker://20.10.22
rxxxx-vm2   Ready    <none>          4h27m   v1.25.5   10.253.137.17   <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   3.10.0-1160.80.1.el7.x86_64   docker://20.10.22
rxxxx-vm3   Ready    <none>          4h27m   v1.25.5   10.253.137.10   <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   3.10.0-1160.80.1.el7.x86_64   docker://20.10.22
```

NGINX Ingress controller is deployed as a daemonset:

```
# kubectl get po -A -o wide
NAMESPACE          NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP              NODE        NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
calico-apiserver   calico-apiserver-685568b969-b8mfr          1/1     Running   0          4h50m   172.17.0.6      rxxxx-vm1   <none>           <none>
calico-apiserver   calico-apiserver-685568b969-xrj2h          1/1     Running   0          4h50m   172.17.0.7      rxxxx-vm1   <none>           <none>
calico-system      calico-kube-controllers-67df98bdc8-2zdnj   1/1     Running   0          4h51m   172.17.0.4      rxxxx-vm1   <none>           <none>
calico-system      calico-node-498bb                          1/1     Running   0          4h51m   10.253.137.20   rxxxx-vm1   <none>           <none>
calico-system      calico-node-sblv9                          1/1     Running   0          4h30m   10.253.137.17   rxxxx-vm2   <none>           <none>
calico-system      calico-node-zkn28                          1/1     Running   0          4h29m   10.253.137.10   rxxxx-vm3   <none>           <none>
calico-system      calico-typha-76c8f59f87-mq52d              1/1     Running   0          4h29m   10.253.137.10   rxxxx-vm3   <none>           <none>
calico-system      calico-typha-76c8f59f87-zk6jr              1/1     Running   0          4h51m   10.253.137.20   rxxxx-vm1   <none>           <none>
kube-system        coredns-787d4945fb-6mq5k                   1/1     Running   0          4h51m   172.17.0.3      rxxxx-vm1   <none>           <none>
kube-system        coredns-787d4945fb-kmqcv                   1/1     Running   0          4h51m   172.17.0.2      rxxxx-vm1   <none>           <none>
kube-system        etcd-rxxxx-vm1                             1/1     Running   0          4h51m   10.253.137.20   rxxxx-vm1   <none>           <none>
kube-system        kube-apiserver-rxxxx-vm1                   1/1     Running   0          4h51m   10.253.137.20   rxxxx-vm1   <none>           <none>
kube-system        kube-controller-manager-rxxxx-vm1          1/1     Running   0          4h51m   10.253.137.20   rxxxx-vm1   <none>           <none>
kube-system        kube-proxy-g9dbt                           1/1     Running   0          4h29m   10.253.137.10   rxxxx-vm3   <none>           <none>
kube-system        kube-proxy-mnzks                           1/1     Running   0          4h30m   10.253.137.17   rxxxx-vm2   <none>           <none>
kube-system        kube-proxy-n98xb                           1/1     Running   0          4h51m   10.253.137.20   rxxxx-vm1   <none>           <none>
kube-system        kube-scheduler-rxxxx-vm1                   1/1     Running   0          4h51m   10.253.137.20   rxxxx-vm1   <none>           <none>
nginx-ingress      nginx-ingress-2chhn                        1/1     Running   0          4h29m   172.17.0.2      rxxxx-vm3   <none>           <none>
nginx-ingress      nginx-ingress-95h7s                        1/1     Running   0          4h30m   172.17.0.2      rxxxx-vm2   <none>           <none>
nginx-ingress      nginx-ingress-wbxng                        1/1     Running   0          4h51m   172.17.0.5      rxxxx-vm1   <none>           <none>
play               apple-app                                  1/1     Running   0          4h45m   172.17.0.8      rxxxx-vm1   <none>           <none>
play               banana-app                                 1/1     Running   0          4h45m   172.17.0.9      rxxxx-vm1   <none>           <none>
tigera-operator    tigera-operator-7795f5d79b-hmm5g           1/1     Running   0          4h51m   10.253.137.20   rxxxx-vm1   <none>           <none>
```

Services:

```
# kubectl get svc -A -o wide
NAMESPACE          NAME                              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE     SELECTOR
calico-apiserver   calico-api                        ClusterIP   10.111.117.42   <none>        443/TCP                  6h34m   apiserver=true
calico-system      calico-kube-controllers-metrics   ClusterIP   10.99.121.254   <none>        9094/TCP                 6h35m   k8s-app=calico-kube-controllers
calico-system      calico-typha                      ClusterIP   10.104.50.90    <none>        5473/TCP                 6h35m   k8s-app=calico-typha
default            kubernetes                        ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP                  6h36m   <none>
kube-system        kube-dns                          ClusterIP   10.96.0.10      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   6h36m   k8s-app=kube-dns
play               apple-service                     ClusterIP   10.98.78.251    <none>        5678/TCP                 6h29m   app=apple
play               banana-service                    ClusterIP   10.103.87.112   <none>        5678/TCP                 6h29m   app=banana
```

Service details:

```
# kubectl -n play describe svc apple-service
Name:              apple-service
Namespace:         play
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=apple
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.98.78.251
IPs:               10.98.78.251
Port:              <unset>  5678/TCP
TargetPort:        5678/TCP
Endpoints:         172.17.0.8:5678
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Endpoints:

```
# kubectl get ep -A
NAMESPACE          NAME                              ENDPOINTS                                               AGE
calico-apiserver   calico-api                        172.17.0.6:5443,172.17.0.7:5443                         6h39m
calico-system      calico-kube-controllers-metrics   172.17.0.4:9094                                         6h39m
calico-system      calico-typha                      10.253.137.10:5473,10.253.137.20:5473                   6h40m
default            kubernetes                        10.253.137.20:6443                                      6h40m
kube-system        kube-dns                          172.17.0.2:53,172.17.0.3:53,172.17.0.2:53 + 3 more...   6h40m
play               apple-service                     172.17.0.8:5678                                         6h34m
play               banana-service                    172.17.0.9:5678                                         6h34m
```

Endpoint details:

```
# kubectl -n play describe ep apple-service
Name:         apple-service
Namespace:    play
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  endpoints.kubernetes.io/last-change-trigger-time: 2023-01-11T20:21:27Z
Subsets:
  Addresses:          172.17.0.8
  NotReadyAddresses:  <none>
  Ports:
    Name     Port  Protocol
    ----     ----  --------
    <unset>  5678  TCP

Events:  <none>
```

Ingress resource:

```
# kubectl get ing -A -o wide
NAMESPACE   NAME              CLASS   HOSTS       ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
play        example-ingress   nginx   localhost             80      6h30m
```

Ingress details:

```
# kubectl -n play describe ing example-ingress
Name:             example-ingress
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        play
Address:
Ingress Class:    nginx
Default backend:  <default>
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  localhost
              /apple    apple-service:5678 (172.17.0.8:5678)
              /banana   banana-service:5678 (172.17.0.9:5678)
Annotations:  ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
Events:       <none>
```

**QUESTION:**
While `curl -kL http://localhost/apple` on master node returns `apple` the same command produces below output on worker nodes:

```
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.23.2</center>
</body>
</html>
```

My understanding is that if the ingress controller pod is running on every node, then `localhost` should be resolved as this is defined as host in ingress resource definition. Is this understanding incorrect? If not, what am I doing wrong?

When I look at the corresponding node's ingress controller's pod's logs, I see this:

```
2023/01/12 03:02:05 [error] 68#68: *11 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /apple HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.8:5678/apple", host: "localhost"
172.17.0.1 - - [12/Jan/2023:03:02:05 +0000] "GET /apple HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "curl/7.29.0" "-"
```

Comment: Have you tried giving a different hostname to ingress rather than **localhost**?Check this [link](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kind/issues/1460) it has similar issue to this. Will it help?